# Filtrar un objeto dependiendo del value seleccionado

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtro

Tengo dos botones en reactjs, el primero corresponde a la filas y el segundo a las columnas, Ambos botones al dar click abren una lista de valores que corresponden a cada uno de ellos, Quisiera que cuando el usuario marque un check de la lista que muestra el boton que esta en el contenedor filas, se genere un filtro en el siguiente boton que solo muestre los valores que corresponden al check marcado.

[image: Estos son los dos botones, vendedor y proveedor. Puede ser cualquier otro.]

Cuando doy click vendedor aparace la lista de vendedores, yo selecciono Ej Jorge, ahora necesito mostrar solo los proveedores que correspondan con Jorge, no todo los proveedores

[image: Aqui selecciono el vendedor que necesito]

Aqui en Proveedores estan apareciendo todos los proveedores de ambos vendedores y no quiero eso. Solo los del vendedor que marque en la otra lista
[image]

Este es mi codigo;

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs";
import {
  consultValuesInTheApi,
  getValuesForCheckbox,
  getArrObject,
} from "../Functions/functions";
import { getData } from "../services/api_aralsoft";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ButtonApp from "./ButtonApp";
import "../assets/styles/Container.css";
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";

const Container = () => {
  let ArrayOfSelectedButtons = [];
  const [row, setRow] = useState([]);
  const [column, setColumn] = useState([]);
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [btnClick, setBtnClick] = useState("");
  const [dataRow, setDataRow] = useState([]);
  const [dataColumn, setDataColumn] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [selectColumn, setSelectColumn] = useState([]);
  const [selectRow, setSelectRow] = useState([]);

  const addToArrayOfSelectedButtons = (button) => {
    if (button != null) {
      ArrayOfSelectedButtons.push(button.textContent);
    }
    return ArrayOfSelectedButtons;
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    setDataRow([]);
    setDataColumn([]);
  };
  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };
  const openFilter = async (state) => {
    openModal();
    if (state === row) {
      const fila = state.toString();
      const resultApiRow = await consultValuesInTheApi(fila);
      getValuesForCheckbox(resultApiRow, setDataRow);
      setBtnClick("fila");
    } else {
      const columna = state.toString();
      console.log(columna);
      const resultApiColumn = await consultValuesInTheApi(columna);
      getValuesForCheckbox(resultApiColumn, setDataColumn);
      setBtnClick("columna");
    }
  };
  const selectReport = [];
  const nameOfSelectedButtons = () => {
    const fila = row.toString();
    const columna = column.toString();
    const valores = values.toString();
    selectReport.push(fila, columna, valores);
    return selectReport;
  };

  /*****************************************************************************/
  const handleSelectColumn = (e) => {
    const valueCheckbox = e.target.value;
    if (selectColumn.includes(valueCheckbox)) {
      setSelectColumn(selectColumn.filter((sel) => sel !== valueCheckbox));
    } else {
      setSelectColumn([...selectColumn, valueCheckbox]);
    }
  };
  const handleSelectRow = (e) => {
    const valueCheckbox = e.target.value;
    if (selectRow.includes(valueCheckbox)) {
      setSelectRow(selectRow.filter((sel) => sel !== valueCheckbox));
    } else {
      setSelectRow([...selectRow, valueCheckbox]);
    }
  };

  /*****************************************************************************/

  const generateReport = async () => {
    
    const resBtnOfReport = nameOfSelectedButtons();
  };
 
  return (
    <div className="bottomContainer">
      <section className="itemsSelected">
        <div className="containerVertical">
          <div className="containerR">
            Filas
            <ReactSortable
              list={row}
              setList={setRow}
              group={{ name: "selectedButton", pull: true }}
            >
              {!row
                ? "Cargando..."
                : row.map((item, index) => (
                    <button
                      className="btnSelect"
                      key={index}
                      ref={(button) => addToArrayOfSelectedButtons(button)}
                      onClick={() => openFilter(row)}
                    >
                      {item}
                    </button>
                  ))}
            </ReactSortable>
          </div>
        </div>
        <article className="container_col_val">
          <div className="containerHorizontal">
            <div className="containerR">
              Columnas
              <ReactSortable
                list={column}
                setList={setColumn}
                group={{ name: "selectedButton", pull: true }}
              >
                {!column
                  ? "Cargando..."
                  : column.map((item, index) => (
                      <button
                        className="btnSelect"
                        key={index}
                        ref={(button) => addToArrayOfSelectedButtons(button)}
                        onClick={() => openFilter(column)}
                      >
                        {item}
                      </button>
                    ))}
              </ReactSortable>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="containerHorizontal">
            <div className="containerR">
              Valores
              <ReactSortable
                list={values}
                setList={setValues}
                group={{ name: "selectedButton", pull: true }}
              >
                {!values
                  ? "Cargando..."
                  : values.map((item, index) => (
                      <button
                        className="btnSelect"
                        key={index}
                        ref={(button) => addToArrayOfSelectedButtons(button)}
                      >
                        {item}
                      </button>
                    ))}
              </ReactSortable>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
        <div className={isOpen ? "block" : "none"}>
          <Checkbox
            state={btnClick}
            stateRow={dataRow}
            stateColumn={dataColumn}
            handleChangeSearch={handleChangeSearch}
            search={search}
            closeModal={closeModal}
            handleSelectColumn={handleSelectColumn}
            handleSelectRow={handleSelectRow}
          ></Checkbox>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <ButtonApp name="Generar Reporte" onClick={generateReport} />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Container;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres, lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la función filter de javascript para filtrar los valores del segundo botón en base a lo seleccionado en el primer botón.

Para ello, cuando el usuario seleccione un valor en el primer botón, puedes guardar ese valor en una variable, por ejemplo selectedValue, y luego utilizar ese valor para filtrar los valores del segundo botón utilizando la función filter. Algo así:

```
const selectedValue = "Jorge";

const filteredValues = dataColumn.filter((value) => value.includes(selectedValue));
```

Luego, en vez de mostrar dataColumn en el segundo botón, puedes mostrar filteredValues.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero en el caso que sean varios los elementos seleccionados, como haria?